# Can use use .artifactignore with MSBuild 15.0?

Tags: azure-devops

We're migrating to Azure DevOps.  Running MSBuild 15.0.  I'm Using .artifactignore in the root of the solution to exclude *.cs files (to start). The build artifacts still contain *.cs files.

I have tried putting the .artifactignore file in the root and in the 'thing' to be built into an artifact and the files are never excluded.

Is there a build version dependency to use .artifactignore?

I am using the 'Publish Build Artifact' task as follows:
[image]

This generates an artifact that contains several file types that I do not want to deploy which include *.cs, and *.csproj such as the following:
**[image: strong text]**

Comment: Why are you trying to ignore `.cs` files instead of just publishing the binary build outputs, which won't include `.cs` files?

Comment: Daniel, I would surmise that we are probably not using Azure DevOps in the same manner.  Binary build outputs, are used in a webpublish or webdeploy if I understand that correctly.  We do not do that.

Comment: You're building C# projects, which result in binary outputs of some variety. You can publish **just** the folder containing the binary outputs.

Comment: Daniel, I do not understand what you are talking about, I'm sorry.  What build tasks are you using? How are you setting those up?I have added more text and some screen shots to clarify my question.  If you want to more fully explain what you are talking about, I would be happy to learn from you.

Comment: 'Publish Build Artifact' has NOTHING to do with msbuild, the title is misleading because you are not having a problem related to msbuild

Comment: Just to clarify this: the task above does not build something, it just uploads a folder. you shouldn't select the sourcecode or the solution but the directory where the binaries from a previous build-task are copied to

Comment: DJ, then can you try reading the comments as well? I did update my question in light of what Daniel was saying.  Is my original question not clear enough to you?  Are you saying that 'Publish Build Artifact' can do what .artifactignore should be doing?  Are you using .artifactignore successfully?

Comment: To clarify.  I am aware of that DJ.  Daniel was under the impression that needed to publish the binary build outputs.  I can't 'just' push the bin folder.  There are other folders that must be pushed with it.  I was providing more detail to help Daniel understand what's going on.

Comment: Then you should either add a post-build target to your MSBuild project to arrange the files properly, add the files to your project and set the build action to `Copy`, or use a Copy Files build task to copy them to an appropriate staging location (such as `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` prior to publishing your artifact.